# Magento "visible" config key not recognized in EAV custom attribute

Tags: magento-1.7, entity-attribute-value

I am using the getDefaultEntities() function which is run from my installer script.  It mostly works, almost all of the attribute config keys reflect properly in the Attributes section of the admin.  However the "visible," "visible_on_front" and some of the other properties do not work at all.  My custom attribute is always set to not visible, not visible on front end.  Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

```
class Ia_AdvancedShipping_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
{
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getDefaultEntities()
{
    return array(
        'catalog_product' => array(
            'entity_model'      => 'catalog/product',
            'attribute_model'   => 'catalog/resource_eav_attribute',
            'table'             => 'catalog/product',
            'additional_attribute_table' => 'catalog/eav_attribute',
            'entity_attribute_collection' => 'catalog/product_attribute_collection',
            'attributes'        => array(
                'iaadvancedshipping_profile' => array(
                    'group'             => 'Advanced Shipping',
                    'label'             => 'Shipping Profiles',
                    'type'              => 'varchar',
                    'input'             => 'select',
                    'source'            => 'iaadvancedshipping/product_attribute_source_profiles',
                    'default'           => '0',
                    'class'             => '',
                    'backend'           => '',
                    'frontend'          => '',
                    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'visible'           => true,
                    'required'          => false,
                    'user_defined'      => false,
                    'searchable'        => false,
                    'filterable'        => false,
                    'comparable'        => false,
                    'visible_on_front'  => true,
                    'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
                    'unique'            => false
                ),
           )
       )
  );
}
}
```